# Python- How do I search through a text file, looking for specific info?

Tags: python

I want to write code that locates every line in the file that begins with “From”, and extracts the portion of the e-mail address located between white space and the “@” symbol.

```
text = open('mBox.txt')

for line in text:
    if line.startswith('From') :
        print line
```

This is what I have so far. Not sure how to make it extract the specific part I want. This is for python 2.7

Comment: What does a full line look like?

Comment: From louis@media.berkeley.edu Fri Jan  4 18:10:48 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.97])
  by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;
  Fri, 04 Jan 2008 18:10:48 -0500

Comment: The file has a big list of parts like that with different emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
for line in text:
    if line.startswith("From"):
        match = re.search(r"(\S+)@", line)
        if match:
            print match.group(1)
```

The `\S` matches any character that is not a space. Since `\S+` will match as much as possible, there's no need to mention the preceding space.

Comment: This one works, but it only gives me the first name. How would I make it go through the entire file and list all the names?

Comment: You are supposed to put this under `for line in text:`. (I thought you know enough python to understand this.)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did but it only gives me the first name. The text file has a lot of them

Comment: Hmm, can you test and confirm that your file is really being read one line at a time? I think you may have a line-ending problem. (The example "line" you posted under the question is really three lines). The code I provided will fetch one email per call, so the loop must actually call it for each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
print line.split("From",1)[-1].split("@").strip()
```

should do what you want .... its one way at least

you could also do it with regex

```
matches = []
matcher=lambda m:matches.append(m.groups(1)) or ""
re.sub("^From\s+(\w+)@.*",text.read())
print matches
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
text = open('mBox.txt')
for line in text:
    if line.split(' ', 1)[0] == 'From':
        .....
```